# Find linear combination with small support

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomial-time

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of a vector subspace of $\Bbbk^N$, say for $\Bbbk$ a finite field. I would like an algorithm to find a linear combination of the $v_i$'s with small support, i.e. with many zero coefficients.

I'm pretty sure it's NP-complete to decide whether there is such a linear combination with at most $K$ nonzeros, so my question is rather whether there are relaxations that are in P: finding a linear combination with provably at most $10$, or $\log(N)$, or ... more nonzeros than the optimum.

I'm also interested in this question in practice: say for $n=10^3$ and $N=10^6$, is there an algorithm that would work in practice?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/150984/755, https://mathoverflow.net/a/421013/37212